# ¿Cómo cambiar nombre de la clave de un objecto con PHP?

Tags: php, php7, objeto

Buen día amig@s; deseo cambiar el nombre de la clave de un objecto con php pero no lo se hacer me pueden ayudar?

Este es mi objecto de ejemplo:

```
$frutas = array(
        [
            "nombre" => "mango",
            "tamaño" => "pequeño"
        ],
        [
            "nombre" => "pera",
            "tamaño" => "mediano"
        ]
    );
```

Lo que deseamos hacer es cambiarle el nombre de la clave **"nombre"** por **"title"**, para cada uno.

De tal forma que si hacemos un `print_r($frutas);` nuestra salida sea algo así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => mango
            [tamaño] => pequeño
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => pera
            [tamaño] => mediano
        )
)
```

El código que llevaba hasta el momento era el siguiente:

```
foreach ($frutas as $key => $value) {
                    if (key($value) == 'nombre') {
                        //Aqui ya no se que poner para cambiar el nombre de la clave
                    }
                }
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar con mi problema y desde ya muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función de PHP [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php):

```
array_walk($frutas, function (& $item) {
   $item['title'] = $item['nombre'];
   unset($item['nombre']);
});


var_dump($frutas);
```

<sup>*Recomendación: evitar utilizar caracteres especiales cómo la `ñ` al programar (lo digo por `tamaño`)</sup>

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funciono a la perfección, y gracias por la recomendación estoy de acuerdo de no utilizar la ñ solo la use para crear un ejemplo más practico aun así muchas gracias.